# Storing several paths as strings inside an array in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wrote the following batch file:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set integer=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('where /R C:\ /F python.exe') do (
    set Paths[!integer!]=%%a
    set /A integer+=1
)

for %%b in (%Paths%) do (
    echo %%b
)
```

The idea is that I want to run `where /R C:\ /F python.exe` and then store the several paths outputted into an array, I need this because I need to handle these paths later on. So far for testing purposes I called the second half of the script just to make sure the array is working properly.

Comment: `set Paths[` would display the stored paths... So you expect the second part to return the stored paths? This cannot work, because ther are no real arrays in batch; there are just normal variables with names like `Paths[0]`, `Paths[1]`, etc., whose names appear like arrays... See also this post: [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10167990).

Comment: ok I see, then I need to know previously how many paths I have and loop over intergers and call `for /L %%i in (0,1,3..<number of paths>) do (echo !vector[%%i]!)`. Or maybe by incrementing `interger` I can use `for /L %%i in (0,1,%integer%)`

Comment: Yes. After the first part, do `set /A count=integer-1` to get the last index, then do `for /L %%i in (0,1,%count%) do echo !Paths[%%i]!`. Alternatively, you could do `for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%i in ('set Paths[ 2^> nul') do echo %%i: %%j` (but this does not return sorted items as soon as there appear indexes woth more than one digit due to alphabetic sorting of `set Paths[`).

Comment: @aschipfl yes, it seems I have 12 Paths, but the first format works fine!

Comment: ... alternatively, you could increment `set /A integer+=1` _before_ `set Paths[!integer!]=%%a` and at end, do the `for /L` from `1` to `%integer%`...

Comment: thank you for your quick responses and help!

Comment: @Aacini, that's somehow a matter of taste whether you prefer base-0 or base-1 arrays; though I have to admit, in batch base-1 arrays seem to be slightly easier to handle sometimes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second part is wrong. Since there are no real arrays in batch scripting, you cannot use a `for` loop similar to something like `for each element in array do` as used in other languages. Refer to this post for details: [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10167990).

To loop through all (pseudo-)array elements you could do the following instead:

```cmd
set /A count=integer-1
for /L %%i in (0,1,%count%) do echo Paths[%%i] = !Paths[%%i]!
```

---

As suggested by [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51193458/storing-several-paths-as-strings-inside-an-array-in-cmd/51195146#comment89370780_51193458), you might change your base-0 to a base-1 (pseudo-)array by moving the line `set /A integer+=1` upwards to be before line `set Paths[!integer!]=%%a` in your first part, so the variable `integer` already contains the greatest index, which would lead to a slightly simpler second part:

```cmd
for /L %%i in (1,1,%integer%) do echo Paths[%%i] = !Paths[%%i]!
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a `for /F` loop that parses the output of `set Paths[`:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%i in ('set Paths[ 2^> nul') do echo %%i = %%j
```

This might be beneficial:

- you do not need to know the total number of elements;
- the indexes do not have to be adjacent, they could even be non-numeric;

But there are two caveats:

- the (pseudo-)array elements are not returned in ascending order with respect to the indexes, because `set Paths[` returns them alphabetically sorted, where the order is `0`, `1`, `10`, `11`,..., `2`, etc., so the order becomes jumbled as soon as there are indexes with more than a single digit;
- in case there exist other variables beginning with that name, like `Paths[invalid]` or `Paths[none`, they become returned too;